# I want to override my tr border using class

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, i want to override the particular css properties through my class , I want to override `border-bottom: 1px solid #e7b2b2;` to `border:none;` to my specific class bidder, remaining table i need this border-bottom. can you anyone help me regarding this. I tried this but not working

```css
.bidder tr {
  border: none !important;
}

table tr,
table th,
table td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7b2b2;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="content" width="100%" bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" class="bidder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">
        <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/Super%20Mono%203D/auction%20hammer.png" width="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span style="font-size:11px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;"> Product Name </span> <br>
        <span style="font-size:14px;  color:#3573a4;"> Testing Scraps redodfi jdfsfjksfjk hkdfs </span>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="right">
        <img src="https://www.allbids.com.au/img/logo_xs.png" width="40"> &nbsp; <img src="http://marketplace.trainzauctions.com/themes/default/img/autobid.png" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet. See how much more useful that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.bidder th, .bidder td` in selector list.

```css
.bidder tr,
.bidder th,
.bidder td{
  border: none !important;
}

table tr,
table th,
table td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7b2b2;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="content" width="100%" bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" class="bidder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">
        <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/Super%20Mono%203D/auction%20hammer.png" width="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span style="font-size:11px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;"> Product Name </span> <br>
        <span style="font-size:14px;  color:#3573a4;"> Testing Scraps redodfi jdfsfjksfjk hkdfs </span>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="right">
        <img src="https://www.allbids.com.au/img/logo_xs.png" width="40"> &nbsp; <img src="http://marketplace.trainzauctions.com/themes/default/img/autobid.png" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the styles for table headings (`<th>`) and table cells (`<td>`) as well ...

```
.bidder tr,
.bidder th,
.bidder td {
  border: none !important;
}
```

... your selector only targets the table row, and not the cells or headings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you hide only tr bottom border. But borders in other two (th,td) elements is still exists. You would give a selector to them too.

Like this. This should hide all borders in table which has bidder class.

```
 .bidder  tr, .bidder th, .bidder td {
            border: none !important;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the following code and it may help you out.

```
table th, table td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7b2b2;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
.bidder th,
.bidder td {
   border: none;
}
```

In your code you are using border:none for only tr element but you are adding border for th and td elements as well. So you need to use border:none for th and td elements too.

Answer (score 2):

Just add td after your `.bidder tr` just like below to target the element inside `tr`.

```css
.bidder tr td {
  border: none !important;
}

table tr,
table th,
table td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7b2b2;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: .875rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="content" width="100%" bgcolor="ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" class="bidder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="50">
        <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/Super%20Mono%203D/auction%20hammer.png" width="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span style="font-size:11px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;"> Product Name </span> <br>
        <span style="font-size:14px;  color:#3573a4;"> Testing Scraps redodfi jdfsfjksfjk hkdfs </span>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="right">
        <img src="https://www.allbids.com.au/img/logo_xs.png" width="40"> &nbsp; <img src="http://marketplace.trainzauctions.com/themes/default/img/autobid.png" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```